# HTML Parser in Objective - C

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, parsing, xpath

I have a script

```
<div class = "des"> 
<span class = "abc"> </span>
*content*
<div> .... </div>
<div>...</div>
</div>
```

I want to take *content*. I used

```
NSString * xPath = @"div[@class='des']";
NSArray * array = [Parser searchWithXPathQuery:xPath];
for (TFHppleElement * ele in array)
{
NSString * content = [ele content];
}
```

However, I just got content = " ". How can I get *content* ?

Comment: When you say you just got content = " ", do you mean inside the `for` loop, or at the end? (The contents after the end of the `for` loop are just whitespace, because that's what the last array element contains.)

Comment: I mean when I debug it, I cannot get any contents as I expect.

Comment: So you mean all the array elements are empty?

Comment: I dont know, I just get content = "" and content = null when I debug. And I want to get "content", how can I fix my code?

Comment: `Parser` & `TFHppleElement` are not part of Cocoa Touch.  So unless you can 1) indicate which Library/Framework you're using; or 2) show your implementations of those classes, I don't think there's much anyone can do to help you.

Comment: Is this a snippet (part of an HTML document) or the full document? If it is a snippet, try with `//div[@class='des']`. You also might have to register namespaces, please post the full document if so (in a gist or wherever).